# Create Json in PHP using database II

Tags: php, json

I have previously asked this question

[Create Json in PHP using database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557882/create-json-in-php-using-database)

which was answered and it worked, however requirement changed a bit and new output that I am trying to get isn't being achieved through this script.

This script give me this output

```
{
"channelsCategories":
    [
        {
            "name":"Movie",
            "contents":
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 1",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 2",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 4",
                        "image":"amazon-logo...",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"High",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    }
            ]

        },
        {
            "name":"Documentary",
            "contents":
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 7",
                        "image":"amazon.....",
                    }
            ]

        }


    ]
}
```

new requirement is to add an image field in category array as well as below.

```
{
"channelsCategories":
    [
        {
            "name":"Movie",
            "image": "MoviePoster",
            "contents":
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 1",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 2",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 4",
                        "image":"amazon-logo...",
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"High",
                        "image":"Thanks.jpg",
                    }
            ]

        },
        {
            "name":"Documentary",
            "image": "MoviePoster",
            "contents":
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Channel 7",
                        "image":"amazon.....",
                    }
            ]

        }


    ]
}
```

So far I have achieved this array result, over which I want to loop and get the above output.

```
array(8) { 
    ["Movieposter"]=> string(7) "Movieposter" 
    ["News"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(8) "Dunya tv" 
            ["url"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(6) "Geo tv" 
            ["url"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
    } 
    ["Dramaimg"]=> string(8) "Dramaimg" 
    ["Drama"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "drama 1" 
            ["url"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "drama 2" 
            ["url"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "4" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
    } 
    ["entertainmentimg"]=> string(16) "entertainmentimg" 
    ["Entertainment"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(8) "indian 1" 
            ["url"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
    } 
    ["Pakistanimg"]=> string(11) "Pakistanimg" 
    ["Pakistan"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> string(8) "pcontent" 
            ["url"]=> string(8) "pcontent" 
            ["image"]=> string(4) "http" 
            ["type"]=> string(1) "7" 
            ["status"]=> string(6) "Enable" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Any help guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? If you understand the basic principles from the previous question, it seems like the modifications should be obvious.

Comment: Just use the solution in that question, and add `'image' => 'MoviePoster'` to the array in the second `foreach` loop.

Comment: I have tried that @Barmar, but it will and it doesn't work as array in second loop has only name and content in it, over which it is being looped. In loop one we are setting only two things name and content. IMO change should be made in first loop first and then in second, but  m unable to figure out what change should be made....

Comment: Can you show the array formatted readably, not all on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that did the work for me .....

```
$typeArr = array();
foreach($result as $a){
    $typeArr[$a['chanct_image']] = $a['chanct_image'];
    $typeArr[$a['chanct_name']][] = array(
        'name'=>$a['con_name'],
        'url'=>$a['con_url'],
        'image'=>$a['con_image'],
        'type'=>$a['con_type'],
        'status'=>$a['con_status']
    );
}

$jsonarray = array();
foreach($typeArr as $type=>$contents){

    if(is_array($contents) == FALSE){
    $image = $type;
    }
    if(is_array($contents))
    {               
        $jsonarray['channelsCategories'][] = array(
            'name'=>$type,
            'image'=>$image,
            'contents'=>$contents
        );
    }
}
```

Added the image field in the first loop, and then in second loop checked that weather the array value was array or string and based on that populated the second jsonarray.

Comment: Use `if/else` instead of two `if` statements that just test the opposite conditions.

Comment: Thnx @Barmar for all the help.